# My svelte inline style doesn't update dynamically when a value is passed into the component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I do not understand what is going on. I am trying to position a dropdown menu using the position of the mouse click in Svelte.

The expected behavior is that the xOffset and yOffset values are passed into the inline style. The actual behavior is that the values stay at the default value of 0.

Here is my code:

`+page.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    const members = [{
        name: "John", email: "j@gmail.com"
    }]

    let dropdownXOffset = 0
    let dropdownYOffset = 0

    function openDropdown(event: PointerEvent) {
        const { clientX, clientY } = event
        dropdownXOffset = clientX
        dropdownYOffset = clientY
    }

    function closeDropdown(event: CustomEvent) {
    }
</script>

<section class="mt-20 mx-auto w-full">
    <Dropdown
        xOffset={dropdownXOffset}
        yOffset={dropdownYOffset}
        on:closeEvent={closeDropdown}
    />
     
        <div class="sm:w-4/5 lg:w-2/5">
            <div>
                <MemberEntry member={members[0]} dropdownOpener={openDropdown} />
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

and in `Dropdown.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let xOffset = 0 // these values are changed
    export let yOffset = 0 // and its reflected beside foo, bar!

</script>

<div
    style="top: {yOffset}, left: {xOffset}" // but this stays the same!
    class=""
>
    <!-- popup -->
    <div class="mt-3 ml-4">
        <div>
            <p class="text-midnight dark:text-sand">foo.{xOffset}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p class="text-midnight dark:text-sand">bar. {yOffset}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I trigger the change of the dropdown location (or would if it worked) by the following
`memberEntry.svelte`

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let member: any

    export let dropdownOpener: Function
</script>

<div class="col-span-2 flex items-center">
    <button on:click={(e) => {dropdownOpener(e)}}>hey</button>>
</div>
```

So the values `foo. {xOffset}` and `bar. {yOffset}` change to numbers, as I expect them to.

But inspecting the browser dev tools shows that the calculated dynamic style is still:

`<div style="top: 0, left: 0" class="">`

*Why doesn't the value propagate to top and left, the inline style?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. You have to separate properties with `;` and positions require units unless they are `0`:

```html
<div style="top: {yOffset}px; left: {xOffset}px">
```

(In case none of the styles set `position`, you will need something like `fixed` or `absolute`, depending on how the popup should behave.)

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/3f474195e5554815b19b91757332615f?version=3.55.1)

Comment: Not only was I missing `px` but I also had commas where a semicolon should be. Thanks!